# Not able to access WP admin Page, redirected and a drop down login menu appears 401 error

Tags: wp-admin, login

I have an issue reaching my Wordpress login page. http://www.everydaytherapy.ie/wp-admin
I am redirected and a drop down menu appears to login in. But not the proper Wordpress login screen (check the URL yourself). I still tried to login but my details didn't work for it. It would just reset. I have tried deleting the .htaccess file, adding the URL's to the config.php file and anything else I could find online. I went into phpMyadmin and the tables seem correct. I deactivated all my plugin's and even my theme and still the same issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a password set up in the .htaccess file or somewhere else on the server. The best thing to do is to contact your web host to see if they can remove it - otherwise, you can delete the .htaccess file in your install which might get around it.

Comment: Thanks a million for the reply. I have tried deleting the .htaccess file from the root folder. But still have the issue. Would there be another .htaccess file some where else as well?

Comment: Hmm, there could be another one higher up in the file structure or in another directory, but usually they don't get accidentally put there - it's a pretty deliberate security setup. 

You might want to look for and try removing `.htpasswd` files if you can find it - otherwise contacting your webhost would be the next step, since they could probably locate what's causing the problem and help fix it. Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

I contacted my web hosting provider about this issue. Because I was out of my native country (Ireland) and in the USA trying to access the admin page and extra layer of security was initiated automatically. They gave me the login details and I was able to get in without a bother. 
Thanks a million regardless Daniel!